# refresh the google ads (adsense) on angular route change

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-routing, rxjs-observables, google-ads-script

i m unable to refresh the google adsense  on route change on layout component
here is my app-routing modue

```
  //app-routing-module
  {
    path: '',
    component: LayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: () => import('./pages/pages.module').then(m => m.PagesModule)
      }
    ]
  },
```

here is pages-routing module

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
  },
```

google ad code is in separate banner component

```
  //banner component ts


  const navEndEvents = this.router.events.pipe(filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd))
    navEndEvents.subscribe((event: any) => {
      this.initGoogleAd();
    });
  private initGoogleAd() {
    try {
      (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});

    } catch (e) { }
  }
```

banner component html

```
  <div>
    <ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:block" data-ad-client="ca-pub-6053771666988490"
                data-ad-slot="9396915897" data-ad-format="auto" data-full-width-responsive="true"></ins>
  </div>
```

Every thing works fine I m unable to rerender the google banner component on layout component

layout component

```
//..some other elements
  <app-banner></app-banner> //google ads not refreshing without reload
//..
```

Home component

```
..some other elements
  <app-banner></app-banner> //works on home component though
..
```

any help will be appreciated thanks

Comment: is init function is calling every time when navigation is ending.have you tried using logs

Comment: @ShivShankarNamdev yes the navEndEvents  code is in ngOninit lock

Answer (score 1):

temporarly solved with rxjs `BehaviorSubject`

// created `BehaviorSubject` in banner service

```
export class BannerService extends ApiService {
  bannerShow  = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true)
}
```

// emitted new value on `NavigationEnd` Observable of router within app component

```
navEndEvents.subscribe((event: any) => {
  this.bannerService.bannerShow.next(false)
  this.bannerService.all(3).subscribe((res: any) => {
    this.bannerService.bannerShow.next(true)
  });
});
```

// subscribed to `bannerShow` Observable with `async`  pipe

```
//layout component ts
<app-banner *ngIf="bannerService.bannerShow | async"></app-banner>
```